# ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" does not populate ErrorVariable

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-3.0, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

#### Issue

When using `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"`, the error variable is not being populated as described in the following documentation: [Handling Errors the PowerShell Way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/).

#### Question

How to prevent the error to be displayed as it is with `-ErrorAction "Continue"` yet still populate the error variable?

##### Bonus question

Is there a way to append the error to the error variable in order to store more than one of them?

#### MWE

##### Script

```
$ErrorActions = @("Continue", "SilentlyContinue", "Stop")
foreach ($ErrorAction in $ErrorActions) {
    Write-Host -Object $ErrorAction -ForegroundColor "Green"
    Get-Item -Path "C:\tmp\error1" -ErrorAction $ErrorAction -ErrorVariable "ErrorMessage"
    Get-Item -Path "C:\tmp\error2" -ErrorAction $ErrorAction -ErrorVariable "ErrorMessage"
    Write-Host -Object "ErrorVariable" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    $ErrorMessage
}
```

##### Output

> Continue
>
> Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\tmp\error1' because it does not exist.
>
> At C:\tmp\mwe.ps1:43 char:5
>
> - ```
>   Get-Item -Path "C:\tmp\error1" -ErrorAction $ErrorAction -ErrorVa ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\tmp\error1:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
>
> Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\tmp\error2' because it does not exist.
>
> At C:\tmp\mwe.ps1:44 char:5
>
> - ```
>   Get-Item -Path "C:\tmp\error2" -ErrorAction $ErrorAction -ErrorVa ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\tmp\error2:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
>
> ErrorVariable
>
> Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\tmp\error2' because it does not exist.
>
> At C:\tmp\mwe.ps1:44 char:5
>
> - ```
>   Get-Item -Path "C:\tmp\error2" -ErrorAction $ErrorAction -ErrorVa ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\tmp\error2:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
>
> SilentlyContinue
>
> ErrorVariable
>
> Stop
>
> Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\tmp\error1' because it does not exist.
>
> At C:\tmp\mwe.ps1:43 char:5
>
> - ```
>   Get-Item -Path "C:\tmp\error1" -ErrorAction $ErrorAction -ErrorVa ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\tmp\error1:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Comment: It works fine for me  (`SilentlyContinue` does not populate the `-ErrorVariable`). Note that (besides the error stream) you're mixing `Write-Host` cmdlets (which *directly* writes to the console) with the pipeline output (which *indirectly* writes "by default" to the console after 300ms when no other cmdlet picks up the items from the pipeline). Try: `Write-Host ($ErrorMessage | Out-String)` instead.

Comment: `SilentlyContinue` populates both `-ErrorVariable` and the `$error` stack.

Comment: @Akaizoku, I provided an answer explaining how the error variables and actions work, but I'm still unclear as to what your issue is. Your code looks to work as expected. You get output in the `SilentlyContinue` phase because you are outputting the `$ErrorVariable` to the pipeline yourself.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest My issue is that in the example the output for `SilentlyContinue` is empty. This however appears to be due to the fact that I have used the default `Out-Host` instead of `Write-Host` as @iRon suggested. Thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Get-ChildItem` as an example:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\nonexist -EA SilentlyContinue -EV silentErr
[bool]$silentErr # ==> True
```

As the documentation you linked to mentions, for `-ErrorVariable` and `$ErrorActionPreference` controls the following behavior when non-terminating errors occur (these do ***not*** affect **terminating errors**):

- `Continue`: Display the error and continue execution.
- `SilentlyContinue`: Hide error but still add it to the `-ErrorVariable`, if specified, and `$error` stack.
- `Stop`: Throws an exception and halts execution. Exceptions may be caught and handled via a `try` / `catch` / `finally` block.

  - **Non-terminating** errors cannot be normally handled via `try` / `catch` / `finally` because an exception isn't thrown unless `-ErrorAction` is `Stop`.
- `Ignore`: The error is swallowed with no indication it occurred. Neither `-ErrorVariable` or the `$error` stack is updated in this case.
- `Inquire`: Ask the operator what to do if an error occurs.

Using the above knowledge, we can still rely on the `$error` automatic variable and the specified
`-ErrorVariable` to be populated if the `-ErrorAction` is `SilentlyContinue`.

> **Note:** You can also use the [`$ErrorView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#errorview) variable to further control how errors are displayed in the console.

---

To answer your sub-question, there is not a mechanism for giving a "named" error stack, but you can use the built-in `$error` stack to keep track of the errors which occur (and didn't occur under
`-EA Ignore`). If you want to ensure you only have errors that occur at a certain point onward in your script/session/etc, you can call the following to clear the error variable:

```
$error.Clear()
```

---

### Additional Information

- **[Terminating Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/terminating-errors?view=powershell-7.1)**
- **[Non-Terminating Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/non-terminating-errors?view=powershell-7.1)**
- **[`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1#erroractionpreference)**
- **[`$Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#error) and [`$ErrorView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#errorview) automatic variables**